# How to call a function after a group or user are created in Buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am trying to save user and group details in an Active Directory (LDAP) after buddypress save the details in mysql database.

Where can I place the code to save user and group details in LDAP. Can I call a function or are there any inbuilt function which can be used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has a mechanism exactly for this: [actions and filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks.2C_Actions_and_Filters).
BuddyPress leverages actions/hooks to provide extension points through which you can customize it without modifying it's sources.

For what you need there's a `do_action( 'bp_core_activated_user', $user_id, $key, $user )` hook defined, so you'd just have to register `add_action( 'bp_core_activated_user', 'bp_core_new_user_activity' )` that will be called with `$user_id, $key, $user` as parameters.

If you search the [documentation](https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/) you'll find most of the hooks. But ideally you'd look at the sources themselves to find appropriate ones.